# regex not working in vim config file

Tags: vim

I have the following regex in one of my ftplugin files, whose purpose is to delimit assignment operators with spaces after I press the enter key:

```
inoremap <CR> <Esc>:s/\s*\([=+!-]\?=\)\s*/ \1 /ge<CR>:noh<CR>o
```

It works on =, ==, !=, +=, -=. So far, that part seems to be working flawlessly. The problem occurs when I modify this regex as follows to delimit comparison operators as well:

```
inoremap <CR> <Esc>:s/\s*\([=+!-]\?=\|[><]=\?\)\s*/ \1 /ge<CR>:noh<CR>o
```

After this change, neither assignment, nor comparison operators are matched anymore (no errors, just nothing happens). However, searching for this new pattern in vim directly highlights all of them. I'm not sure if the issue is due to < and > being special characters in .vim files (used for <CR>, etc.), I tried escaping them with \, but that didn't seem to help. Also, when I put them inside the same block as the rest of the operators, they work fine:

```
inoremap <CR> <Esc>:s/\s*\([=+!-><]\?=\)\s*/ \1 /ge<CR>:noh<CR>o
```

The only problem in this case, however, is that if I type something like x<y, it will not insert spaces there since there is no equal sign (and if I make equal sign optional, it will force spaces between all +/-/! operators, which I don't really want, since I sometimes want to use them to make grouping more obvious (.i.e `x = (a+b+c+d+e+f) - (g+h+i)` rather than `x = (a + b + c + d + e + f) - (g + h + i)`). Likewise, I don't want my negations to look like `if( ! (statement) ...`. What am I doing wrong? Also, I'm using vim 7.2.245. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the amount of `magic` specifically in your regex:

```
inoremap <CR> <CR>a<Esc>mz:-1s/\v\s*([=+!-<>]?\=\|[<>])\s*/ \1 /ge<CR>:nohls<CR>`zcl
```

Note also, I employed <kbd>C-o</kbd> to issue the substitute *from insert mode*

Breakdown

- `<CR>a` execute the <kbd>Enter</kbd> as normal, insert a dummy character (`'a'`)
- `<Esc>` leave insert mode
- `mz`   save cursor position in register `z`
- `:-1s/\v.../.../g` on the *previous line* (`-1`) perform a global substitution with `very-magic` *on*
- `:nohls<CR>` hide search highlighting
- `` `z `` restore saved cursor position
- `cl` enter insert mode, overwriting the earlier dummy character

Comment: Posted my cursor restore version. You'll find that my version works well when splitting lines in the middle (pressing <CR> halfway a line) and preserving indentation

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize that my version breaks when splitting an existing line with newline. One issue I'm still seeing with your version is that the register only seems to be working when splitting the line, not for newline, but I can't seem to figure out why. The only thing I can think of is because I'm using an indent script (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=974) rather than regular smartindent

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4936/discussion-between-sehe-and-user507078)